# Bind group data to Gridview windows 8 store app

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

This is my first win 8 store app using XAML, so kind of not sure about few things. I want to bind data to a gridview. To do this, I have a

```
class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
}
```

in the code behind, i have

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        // TODO: Assign a bindable collection of items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]
        Model.Utility util = new Utility();
        var categories = util.GetCategoryList(); // this returns List<Category>
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = categories;
    }
```

and my xaml is:

```
  <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"/>
```

But I dont see any data when I run the app. Where am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Standard250x250ItemTemplate binds to the properties Title, SubTitle and Image by default.  Unless you have updated the template, your Category class does not have those properties to the ItemTemplate does not have anything to display.  I suspect there are databinding errors VS when you debug the apps saying the Title,SubTitle and Image properties cannot be found.

To correct this, right-click on the GridView, selected Edit Additonal Templates, Edit Generated Items (ItemTemplate), Edit a Copy and update the template to bind the correct elements to the property names on your class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the names in your code, it looks like you're trying to reuse some of the template code for the Grid App template.

I'm also going to assume you've got the following resource defined in that same XAML file:

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Items}" />
```

If so, you should be seeing rectangles for each of your categories but no data.  That would be because you are referencing the `Standard250x250ItemTemplate` data template (in StandardStyles.xaml), and it is looking for specific fields in your data source with names like `Title` and `Subtitle`.  But for Categories, you have `CategoryName` and `Id`.

Try this instead and see if your data appears. This doesn't have any styling on it, but you can copy the styling from `Standard250x250ItemTemplate` and adapt if you want. And you can do this through the IDE - Blend or Visual Studio - you don't have to cut and paste XAML.

```
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Padding="116,136,116,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"

    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="false">

    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```